# How can I put label text under icon in Angular Material Stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I couldn't find a way to put label text under stepper icon in [Angular Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples). I want to have an [Icon with under text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad1yY.png) but I couldn't find from documentation. I am using the latest version of [Angular Material UI](https://material.angular.io/). I tried with html and css/scss styles, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this option is available from material@9.
Here you have an example.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/deodkmpnkll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-label-position-bottom-example.ts